# What means "obey ODR" in case of inline and constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++11, inline, constexpr, one-definition-rule

I just read that constexpr and inline functions obey one-definition rule, but they definition must be identical. So I try it:

```
inline void foo() {
    return;
}

inline void foo() {
    return;
}

int main() {
    foo();
};
```

error: redefinition of 'void foo()',
and

```
constexpr int foo() {
    return 1;
}

constexpr int foo() {
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    constexpr x = foo();
};
```

error: redefinition of 'constexpr int foo()'

So what exactly means that, constexpr and inline function can obey ODR?

Comment: It means you can have multiple definitions of them *in different translation units*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just read that constexpr and inline functions obey one-definition rule, but they definition must be identical.

This is in reference to inline functions in different translations units.  In your example they are both in the same translation unit.

This is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) `3.2` One definition rule *[basic.def.odr]* which says:

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), **inline function with
>   external linkage** (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.6), static data member
>   of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for
>   which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given
>   such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then

and includes the following bullet:

> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining functions repeatedly *in one translation unit*. This is always forbidden:

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration
>   type, or template. (C++11 3.2/1)

For `inline` functions, you are allowed to define same function in exactly the same way in more than one translation unit (read: .cpp file). In fact, you *must* define it in every translation unit (which is usually done by defining it in a header file):

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used. (C++11 3.2/3)

For "normal" (non-inline, non-constexpr, non-template, etc.) functions with external linkage (non-static) functions, this will usually (no diagnostic required) lead to a linker error.

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used
>   in that program; no diagnostic required. (C++11 3.2/3)

To sum up:

- Never define anything multiple times in one translation unit (which is a .cpp file and all directly or indirectly included headers).
- You may put a certain number of things into header files, where they will be included *once* in several different translation units, for example:

  - `inline` functions
  - `class` types and `template`s
  - `static` data members of a `class template`.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

file1.cpp:

```
inline void foo() { std::cout << "Came to foo in file1.cpp" << std::endl; }
```

and

file2.cpp:

```
inline void foo() { std::cout << "Came to foo in file2.cpp" << std::endl; }
```

and you link those files together in an executable, you are violating the `one-definition-rule` since the two versions of the `inline` function are not same.

Comment: Good explanation.